# Starting Web App on Android from a notification click in a service worker

Tags: android, web-applications, service-worker

From the sample code on the Goggle web site I can see how to look for and either focus on or start a url in the Browser on the Android device when a notification is clicked. But what I need to do is look for and either focus or start a Web App that the user has added to their home screen.

This is the sample code from Google to start a url such as https://www.google.co.uk/

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('Notification click: tag ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();
    var url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/';
    event.waitUntil(
            clients.matchAll({
                type: 'window',
            })
            .then(function (windowClients) {
                for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                    var client = windowClients[i];
                    if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                        return client.focus();
                    }
                }
                if (clients.openWindow) {
                    return clients.openWindow(url);
                }
            })
            );
});
```

Let’s say that the start url in my Progressive Web App is https://www.myWebApp.co.uk/ ,  That app is now added to the home screen and has a service worker that listens for the push event. That all works great. I need to adapt the above code to check is that url is running as a web app and focus on it, or if not then start and focus on that app when a notification is clicked .

I have tried changing this to just my URL but  it opens a new browser window not my Progressive web app.

Any ideas